# Always Use Same Range For Chart, Even After Inserting Rows

Tags: excel, charts

I currently have a macro that inserts new information every day in the top of a table and bumps the old data down.  I want to have a chart that depicts the first 7 days of data.

What keeps happening is when the chart updates for the new day, the chart is still pulling data from the 7 previous days rather than bumping up to incorporate the newest day.

How Do I Fix This?  I Essentially Just Want to Permanently Set where the charts data comes from so that it doesn't change when rows are inserted above.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the record macro option for this. Just start recording, update your references and stop recording. As you always want to use the same references you can record it once and you won't need to change anything in it, then you can just run that as part of your other macro.